# SFTP server write permissions for group

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sftp, vsftpd

I know there are a lot of questions on this, but nothing worked for me.
So I have a ftp server on Ubuntu 4.8 with sshd enabled. I would like to have write permissions for the group of the owner on every file uploaded.

Right now the permissions of the folder are: `drwxrwxr-x`
And every file uploaded have the permissions `-rw-r--r--`

What I have tried but doesn't change anything at all (using FileZilla `3.21.0` or `sftpd` command directly on Mac):

- setting `local_mask=0002` in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`
- setting `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 002` or `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 0002` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

I did restart `vsftpd` and `sshd`, but still have only read permissions for the group. What is the reason for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Ubuntu 4.8"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton `Linux version 3.13.0-92-generic (buildd@lgw01-52) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) )`, just in case this helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SFTP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02#section-6.9) includes an operation for the client to set attributes for files on the server. This means that SFTP clients can set permissions on uploaded files, regardless of the umask.

I can think of three ways to accomplish what you want:

1. Ask the remote user to set his client to disable setting permissions on uploaded files, assuming that's possible. For example, you can see a setting for that in [this WinSCP dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_preset).
2. Set up an automated process on the server to sweep the directory containing these files, and adjust permissions on any newly uploaded files.
3. Disable the SSH_FXP_SETSTAT operation in the SFTP server. For the [OpenSSH server](http://www.openssh.com/), you'd have to alter the source code for the [sftp-server](http://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server) program. There are commercial SSH/SFTP solutions on the market, and one of them may permit disabling this feature.

Comment: thanks for confirming all of this, I am going to go with changing the permissions automatically on the server